Exterior Window Trims & Caulk
I need to redo caulk around multiple exterior windows. Many windows have trim that is flush with the siding (cedar shingles), caulk is either cracked or completely gone. I was thinking of putting wider wood trims around the windows so that the trim would sit something like 1/2 to 1 inch above the siding.
I have noticed that the cedar shingles sit on top of horizontal furrings, which to my understanding could be bad for water drainage. Fortunately, everywhere I tested the OSB, it "tocks" and it seems I do not have rot damage.
Questions:
If the window trim overlaps by 1 inch, would it be best to leave it un-caulked on the side of the siding (Marked A on pic below) and caulk the side of the window (marked B on pic below)? If any water finds its way under the siding, this would allow water to evaporate and go out from these "holes".
I was thinking of changing the rigid head flashing to make the whole width (trim included, see red line on pic below), currently rigid flashing is only as window as the window itself. Since the house is cedar shingles it's hard to ensure no water could go through from the top trim. Having rigid flashing that goes for the whole width would ensure that if any water goes there it goes out and does not sit behind the side trims on the horizontal furrings.
Any tips would be greatly appreciated!
https://preview.redd.it/exterior-window-trims-caulk-v0-n9ie4sgrc1id1.jpg?width=4284&format=pjpg&auto=webp&s=9851a12f3120492ce654ed3cb3637a218ebbddf2

Sorry your question got lost here. I can't see images on Reddit. Please put it on a proper image host instead.
